# perform ttest on a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, t-test

Trying to perform ttest (and to get p.value) from a data.frame, there's one column that includes the groups (good vs bad) and the rest of the columns are numeric.

I generated a toy dataset here:

```
W <- rep(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 2)], 25)
X <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 10, sd = 5)
Y <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 15, sd = 6)
Z <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 20, sd = 5)
test_data <- data.frame(W, X, Y, Z)
```

Then I transform the data into long format:

```
melt_testdata <- melt(test_data)
```

And performed the t.test

```
lapply(unique(melt_testdata$variable),function(x){
  Good <- subset(melt_testdata, W  == 'a' & variable ==x)$variable
  Bad <- subset(melt_testdata, W == 'b' & variable ==x)$variable
  t.test(Good,Bad)$p.value
})
```

But I instead of getting the t.test results, I got the following error messages:

```
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) :
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is deprecated and will become an error.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
3: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In var(y) :
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is deprecated and will become an error.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
```

Then I tried to write loops (first time..)

```
good <- matrix(,50)
bad <- matrix(,50)
cnt=3
out <- rep(0,cnt)


for (i in 2:4){
  good[i] <- subset(test_data, W == 'a', select= test_data[,i])
  bad[i] <- subset(test_data, W == 'b', select= test_data[,i])
  out[i] <- print(t.test(good[[i]], bad[[i]])$p.value)
}
```

Still not getting p.values .......
This is the error messages

```
Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I appreciate any help in any method, thanks!

Comment: Simply use `$value` instead of `$variable` as t-test require numeric vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have better luck with the `formula` method of `t.test`.  Try

```
library(broom)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

W <- rep(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 2)], 25)
X <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 10, sd = 5)
Y <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 15, sd = 6)
Z <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 20, sd = 5)
test_data <- data.frame(W, X, Y, Z)

lapply(test_data[c("X", "Y", "Z")],
       function(x, y) t.test(x ~ y),
       y = test_data[["W"]]) %>% 
  lapply(tidy) %>% 
  do.call("rbind", .) %>% 
  mutate(variable = rownames(.))
```

### Edit:

With stricter adherence to the `dplyr` philosophy, you can use the following: which is actually a bit cleaner looking.

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

W <- rep(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 2)], 25)
X <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 10, sd = 5)
Y <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 15, sd = 6)
Z <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 20, sd = 5)

test_data <- data.frame(W, X, Y, Z) 

test_data %>% 
  gather(variable, value, X:Z) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  do(., tidy(t.test(value ~ W, data = .)))
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I also tested it on my larger dataset and was fine too. Thanks a lot. I changed test_data[c("X", "Y", "Z")] to test_data[2:4], which is still working, that's great!!

Comment: Yes.  If your grouping variable is your first column, you could also do `test_data[-1]` and get the same result.

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, but what does the . after data = mean (last line)?

Comment: It's a place holder.  If you look at `?do`, the arguments are `do(.data, ...)`.  By putting `.` in the first argument, it takes the data frame coming from the previous call.  Putting it into `data = .` in `t.test` passes that data onto the function.  (I'm not sure that made any sense)

Comment: Thank you Ben, this is really helpful. i will read up the function and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and the formula argument to `t.test`. `do` works on each group defined by the `group_by.` `glance` extracts values from the `t.test` output and makes them into a `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

melt_testdata %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  do(glance(t.test(value ~ W, data = .)))
```

Comment: Thank you @Richard Telford, it works well. What does data = . mean?

Comment: the `.` a part of the data.frame `melt_testdata`, which get split by `variable`. The data argument to `t.test` lets the formula access the variable in the data.frame (you get the same thing in `lm`)